# Rename a Parse Platform class

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone in the Parse Platform community know if it's possible to rename a Parse class?  E.g. I've got a class called Products and I'd like to rename it to Product.

Is this possible or do I need to do a full migration of all the data?

Answer (score 0):

I found this github issue which was super helpful and lead me to the answer:  https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/617

All I had to do was:

1. Rename the collection in the db (db.Products.renameCollection('Product')
2. Find the schema (db.getCollection("_SCHEMA").findOne({_id: "Products"})) and make a copy, update the _id and insert it.
3. Write a quick script to update all pointers in my Product records to point to className of "Product" rather than "Products".
4. Remove the old Products schema

Everything seems to be working as expected.